# Show page in an archive subdirectory if 404 in root Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to get support to set up a correct URL redirect.

**Main website (Wordpress)**

- Wordpress installed on the root
- Custom Permalink structure: https://mywebsite.com/%postname%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%post_id%/

**Archive**

There is an /archive subdirectory where a single index.php and .htaccess already manage to do the following task correctly:

- read the URL with this structure: https://mywebsite.com/archive/%postname%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%post_id
- grab post_id
- show the corresponding content

Current .htaccess in /archive (can be removed/edited if needed)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /archive/index.php [NC,L]
```

**Goal to achieve**

If the page is not is the main website, show the page in the archive subfolder (keeping the same URL without /archive for SEO reasons).

My initial trials were about using this command to intercept 404 (and show a simple html test file in the root):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /test.html
```

but Wordpress still shows the 404.php of the template, instead of the test.html page (so this command seems ignored at all). Reading the Wordpress documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) they say in "*Help Your Server Find the 404 Page*" section that "*If you are using the custom permalink, the trick below does not work*". Therefore a different solution could be required.

Comment: In archive folder its only 1 file (the test.html)?  or multiple files?  If multiple which files do you expect it to show?

Comment: edited the first post with additional information.